# Why is the 14th character in a GUID generated by Visual Studio sometimes lowercase

Tags: visual-studio, guid

Occasionally when I generate a GUID using visual studio, the 14th hex character is lowercase while the rest of the hex digits are uppercase.

Cause a bit of problem when comparing the string representations of two GUIDs.  Now I always compare the binary equivalents to be safe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a [**known bug**](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361975). But you shouldn't be making string comparisons; use  [**`Guid.Equals`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.equals(VS.71).aspx) instead.