# Why does Create GUID display different GUID parts with different capitalization?

Tags: visual-studio, guid, create-guid

Visual Studio is shipped with a Create GUID tool that is used for generating GUIDs. Now here's a GUID it generated for me:

```
{7A09BF85-9E98-44ea-9AB5-A13953E88C3D}
```

each of the 4 GUID parts contains both letters and digits. Why does the third part contain only lowercase letters and other only upcase letters? Is there any sence behind that?

Comment: hmmm, never actually noticed that. But still its a GUID and you'll be mostly using it for definitions so I guess you wont do any case sensitive string comparison with it.

Comment: Nice observation.  That's hilarious.

Comment: Another nice observation that every 3rd part begins with "4". I mean: 
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4XXXX-....
{567E1ECB-EA1C-42d3-A3ED-87A5D824D167}
{20B3D050-1BC5-4d40-85F4-58482018404C}

Comment: Restuta: That's the UUID version number. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier

Comment: oh, I've found explanation of my observaton, it is posted here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier

as for VS I think it is just tricky implementation =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the accepted answer by [John Feminella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75170/john-feminella) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872298/why-is-the-14th-character-in-a-guid-generated-by-visual-studio-sometimes-lowercas), in which he links to [this MS Connect bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361975) (which, by the way, MS has promised to have solved "in the next release" of VS).